# Why Is Garbage Collection So Important?

Tags: garbage-collection

I don't understand garbage collection so good, then I want to know, why it's so important to a language and to the developer?

Comment: Because so few people do memory management themselves well.

Comment: I like that one. I also like to think of it as a modern programming luxury ; just like associative arrays.

Comment: I'm having a hard time to agree with the answers here. I think that with a well-established system you could manage your memory (i.e. smart pointers) without getting "too technical" or away from your logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Garbage Collection is a part of many modern languages that attempts to abstract the disposal and reallocation of memory with less direction intervention by the developer.

When you hear talk of "safe" objects, this usually refers to something whose memory can be automatically reallocated by the Garbage Collector after an object falls out of scope, or is explicitly disposed.

While you can write the same program without a garbage collector to help manage memory usage, abstracting this away lets the developer think about more high level things and deliver value to the end user more quickly and efficiently without having to necessarily concentrate as much on lower level portions of the program.

In essence the developer can say

**Give me a new object**

..and some time later when the object is no longer being used (falls out of scope) the developer does not have to remember to say

**throw this object away**

Developers are lazy (a good virtue) and sometimes forget things.  When working with GC properly, it's okay to forget to take out the trash, the GC won't let it pile up and start to smell.

Comment: About your sentence "... the developer does not have to remember to say throw this object away": I do not agree. To throw an object away, the programmer uses assignments, memory overwrites in the program, and returns from functions. There is no such thing as "not saying to throw an object away". The programmer **is** saying it, but is unaware of it most of the time. GC works because most of the object-away-throwing is **naturally** encoded in the program statements written by the programmer. Note that there are cases when the programmer has to overwrite a reference manually to **help the GC**.

Comment: The problems in non-GC systems aren't generally a result of "forgetting" to throw an object away.  Rather, the problem is that a policy of "Would the last one to leave the room, please turn out the lights" only works well if those who are leaving the room can easily see if anyone else is there.  Having people switch off the lights when they're leaving rooms they think are empty, when they can't really tell for sure, is dangerous.  Having a custodian periodically lock a room, check if it's occupied, and then switch out the lights before leaving if it was empty can be much safer.

Answer (score 20):

Many other answers have stated that garbage collection can help to prevent memory leaks but, surprisingly, nobody seems to have mentioned the most important benefit that GC facilitates *memory safety*. This means that most garbage collected environments completely abstract away the notion of memory locations (i.e. raw pointers) and, consequently, eliminate a major class of bugs.

For example, a common mistake with manual memory management is to accidentally free a value slightly too early and continue to use the memory at that location after it has been freed. This can be extremely difficult to debug because freed memory might not be reallocated and, consequently, seemingly valid operations can be performed on the freed memory that can only fail sporadically with corruption or memory access violations or segmentation faults later in the program's execution, often with no direct link back to the offending code. This class of bugs simply do not exist in most garbage collected environments.

Comment: As an ex-Delphi developer, I can say: "Amen to that!".

Comment: Excellent answer.  I suspect that for most mutable objects, deterministic disposal would really not be much harder than non-deterministic disposal, since mutable objects should generally have a clearly-defined owner, but that even with objects that have clearly-defined ownership, being able to ensure that non-owner references can't access stray memory is very valuable.

Comment: "since mutable objects should generally have a clearly-defined owner". If your program uses a graph with mutable edges and vertices which can shed unreachable subgraphs that are then eligible for collection, who would their "clearly-defined owner" be?

Answer (score 6):

Garbage Collection is a form of automatic memory management. It is a special case of resource management, in which the limited resource being managed is memory.

Benefits for the programmer is that garbage collection frees the programmer from manually dealing with memory allocation and deallocation.

Comment: The deallocation may be taken care of for you, but the allocation you will still have to cause one way or another.

Answer (score 4):

The bottom line is that [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) **helps** to prevent memory leaks. In .NET, for example, when nothing references an object, the resources used by the object are flagged to be garbage collected. In unmanaged languages, like C and C++, it was up to the developer to take care of cleaning up.

It's important to note, however, that garbage collection isn't perfect. Check out [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/showcase/IfOnlyWedUsedANTSProfiler.aspx?display=PrintAll&fid=480602&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26) on a problem that occurred because the developers weren't aware of a large memory leak.

Comment: GC does help **memory management** (you don't have to allocate memory and free it yourself) but doesn't prevent memory leaks.

Comment: That's what I tried to infer by making "helps" bold, in addition to linking to a real-world example of where it doesn't always work, as expected.

Answer (score 3):

In many older and less *strict* languages deallocating memory was hard-coded into programs by the programmer; this of course will cause problems if not done correctly as the second you reference memory that hasn't been deallocated your program will break. To combat this garbage collection was created, to automatically deallocate memory that was no longer being used. The benefits of such a system is easy to see; programs become far more reliable, deallocating memory is effectively removed from the design process, debugging and testing times are far shorter and more.

Of course, you don't get something for nothing. What you lose is performance, and sometimes you'll notice irregular behaviour within your programs, although nowadays with more modern languages this rarely is the case. This is the reason many typical applications are written in Java, it's quick and simple to write without the trauma of chasing memory leaks and it does the job, it's perfect for the world of business and the performance costs are little with the speed of computers today. Obviously some industries need to manage their own memory within their programs (the Games industry) for performance reasons, which is why nearly all major games are written in C++. A lecturer once told me that if every software house was in the same area, with a bar in the middle you'd be able to tell the game developers apart from the rest because they'd be the ones drinking heavily long into the night.

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collection is one of the features required to allow the automatic management of memory allocation.  This is what allows you to allocate various objects, maybe introduce other variables referencing or containing  these in a fashion or other, and yet never worry about disposing of the object (when it is effectively not in use anymore).

The garbage collection, specifically takes care of "cleaning up" the heap(s) where all these objects are found, by removing unused objects an repacking the others together.

You probably hear a lot about it, because this is a critical function, which happens asynchronously with the program and which, if not handled efficiently can produce some random performance lagging in the program, etc. etc.  Nowadays, however the algorithms related to the memory management at-large and the GC (garbage collection) in particular are quite efficient.

Another reason why the GC is sometimes mentioned is in relation to the destructor of some particular object.  Since the application has no (or little) control over when particular objects are Garbage-Collected (hence destroyed), it may be an issue if an object waits till its destructor to dispose of some resource and such.  That is why many objects implement a Dispose() method, which allow much of that clean-up (of the object itself) to be performed explicitly, rather than be postponed till the destructor is eventually called from the GC logic.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic garbage collection, like java, reuses memory leaks or memory that is no longer being used, making your program efficient. In c++, you have to control the memory yourself, and if you lose access to a memory, then that memory can no longer be used, wasting space.
This is what I know so far from one year of computer science and using/learning java and c++.

Answer (score -2):

Because someone can write code like

consume(produce())

without caring about cleanup. Just like in our current society.